# Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:api' after it has been included in dependency resolution

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Cannot change dependencies of configuration **':app:api'** after it has been included in dependency resolution.

Comment: what are your error msgs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle project sync failing after Google announced the new sdk versioning system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166102/gradle-project-sync-failing-after-google-announced-the-new-sdk-versioning-system)

Answer (score 25):

I was also getting the same error. Thanks to [@Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1653268/dominik-kunicki) for linking to the duplicate [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166102/gradle-project-sync-failing-after-google-announced-the-new-sdk-versioning-system).

For now the work around is to downgrade `com.google.gms:google-services` to version `3.2.1` while the Android team works on a fix.

Answer (score 5):

For today you can use

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Seems it works.