# Gradle project sync failing after Google announced the new sdk versioning system

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:api' after it has been included in dependency resolution.
```

**Updated:**
I am able to build using `com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0` when data binding is disabled, but this is not a solution for someone that requires data binding to be enabled.

After Google announced the new sdk versioning system ([link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/)), I did the following steps:

1. I updated the gradle files as directed to include the gms and firebase version numbers separately. Updated the apply plugin line, updated the classpath. I am still getting the error and dont know the reason.
2. Below are relevant gradle files:

build.gradle (main):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/rvalerio/maven' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Firebase dependencies:

```
//Firebase Dependencies
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2"
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

GMS and other dependencies

```
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
```

3. I have pasted the error log on pastebin from android studio 3.1.2 [here](https://pastebin.com/D11dX89V).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please also add your `build.grade` file that contains Firebase dependencies.

Comment: are you using other modules or just app module ? you should also post your modules build.gradle file

Comment: I could reproduce the same issue when turned on **data binding** in app module while using `google-services:3.3.0`.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I have added the build.gradle file dependencies that I have for firebase, GMS and support library.

Comment: @j2emanue I am only using the app module, nothing else. I have posted the build.gradle file. I wonder if only a small group is facing this issue...

Comment: Just curious--why are you including [deprecated GCM lib](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) and also Firebase messaging?  Also, is there a reason you are using 26.1.0 of the Support Libs when 27.1.1 is available?

Comment: @BobSnyder I had forgotten to take out the GCM. I took it out and updated to 27.1.1 but the issue persists!

Comment: Is this issue resolved?Even I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Rohit no, the issue is still being worked on, you can see the status update on google bug tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79122163. In the meantime, downgrading to 3.2.1 seems to work with data bindind set to true.

Comment: ok i will try by downgrading it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to have been resolved by using the new google-services release (4.0.1 as of today). Below is the relevant versions that will resolve the stated issue:

In your project build.gradle files:

```
dependencies { 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' }
```

In your app build.gradle files:

```
//Firebase Dependencies
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'

...} apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Databinding is set to true as well:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Android Studio version: `3.1.2`

Thank you all for providing various ways you can get around the problem, such as the answer by @Kyle and the medium post link that shows you how to use firebase without google services.

Answer (score 15):

managed to build against Play Services & Firebase `15.0.0` **with data-binding enabled** ...my dependencies now look about alike this and it builds again, without any `Cannot change dependencies of configuration` complaints:

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2"

        // do not update, because 3.3.1 appears broken
        // classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1"

        // meanwhile, there is version 4.0.2 available
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2"
    }
}
```

one has to reference all the libraries individually. just referencing `com.google.android.gms:play‐services` and/or `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` does not work anymore since `15.0.0`.

```
android {

    dependencies {

        // Play Services 15.0.0
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1"

        // Firebase 15.0.0
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.2.0"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

also had to edit the `Manifest.xml` to fix the support library:

```
<application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="27.1.1"
        tools:replace="android:value"/>

</application
```

Comment: you are right, that if you are on 3.2.1 and enable data binding, then it builds. However, I want to google to know/show that 3.3.0 is broken when data binding is enabled. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @kash when adding annotation `//noinspection GradleDependency` it does not even suggest to update to `3.3.0`- it's just a cosmetic fix. at least it builds with `3.2.1`.

Comment: the problems begin, when adding `classpath "com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.0.0"` ...which had also been introduced together with `3.3.0`. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html ...it probably just cannot strictly match those alpha build versions (to whatever); in the release notes, the page where the versioning should be explained is 404.

Comment: now there is `3.3.1` ...while I still get the same error message.

Comment: I am getting org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' error with data-binding error enabled.when I ran gradlew assemble --stacktrace I got error in databinding generated file.How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @Rohit downgrade to the latest working version... as my answer might try to suggest. or disable the data-binding library and wait for the next working version.

Comment: @MartinZeitler after disabling databinding I am getting unable to merge dex files error.

Comment: @Rohit I did not suggest to disable that, ever. please read & understand the above answer, there is nothing to add to it and there currently is no fix available, which might be either the next version `3.3.2` and/or an updated version of the data-binding library.

Answer (score 5):

The issue with data binding and the `3.3.0` version of the `google-services` plugin has been reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79122163

As of today, the bug is in the "assigned" state.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
I could compile also with

```
dataBinding.enabled false
```

In android configuration and version 3.3.0

**ORIGINAL**

Same problem here with google-services:3.3.0, which is the last version, but according to [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) version 3.2.1 should be used. I've been able to compile with the following

```
 ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    firebaseCore = '15.0.2'
    authentication = '15.1.0'
    cloudFirestore = '16.0.0'
    cloudStorage = '15.0.2'
    crashlitics = '2.9.1'
    googleServices = '15.0.0'
    supportLibrary = '27.1.1'
    facebookSdkVersion = '4.31.0'
    twitterSdkVersion = '3.1.1'
    firebaseUI = '3.3.1'
}
 dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha12'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
```

Comment: I was able to build with data binding set to false, but this is not exactly a solution to the issue for someone that requires data binding. So I will leave it open till we find a solution and will edit the question to say that... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just downgrade your GooglePlay services dependency to 3.2.1 :)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

While not a great solution, I followed the recommendation from a Googler mentioned on the bug tracker.

I am using

```
com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1
```

I have enabled databinding

```
`dataBinding.enabled true`
```

I removed the plugin reference from the app gradle script

```
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And followed the recommendations from this Medium post to include all of the necessary Google Service string values.

https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4

My app builds successfully and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked after I added the google() maven inside the allProjects block in my project build.gradle like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

repositories {
    ...
}

// You need to add the google maven in this block.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: I do have the google() inside all projects but still getting that error... I dont think its anything to do with where the repository is added. I believe its to do with databinding and the new google repositories.