# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.2

Tags: firebase, build.gradle, firebase-invites

I'm trying to update to the 15.x API version of the Firebase products. Somehow the firebase-invites:15.0.2 cannot be found:

```
Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.2.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/D:/SDK/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.pom
    file:/D:/SDK/extras/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.jar
    file:/D:/SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.pom
    file:/D:/SDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.jar
    file:/D:/SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.pom
    file:/D:/SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.jar
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.jar
    https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.pom
    https://jitpack.io/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/firebase/firebase-invites/15.0.2/firebase-invites-15.0.2.jar
Required by:
    project :app
```

I do have the Google maven repositories in my root build.gradle:

Answer (score 7):

I have faced same problem. I just upgrade the class path of root build grad 
**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'**

In Root gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no version 15.0.2 of firebase-invites yet.  15.0.1 is the latest version.

The versioning scheme of Firebase and Play services libraries has changed recently.  Perhaps you are still using a variable in gradle to manage all your versions.  That pattern is no longer valid.  The details are in [this blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html).

Comment: The version number is incorrect in the [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: Yes, it's showing 15.0.2 in the release notes, when I change the dependency to 15.01, I get: CONFIGURE FAILED in 1s
Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:api' after it has been included in dependency resolution...

Comment: @Peter: The "configure failed" problem is [reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50166102/4815718); no solution posted yet.

Comment: they have updated it, 15.0.1 is latest version according to the release notes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Resolved it by changing from 15.0.2 to 15.0.1 as give below:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
```